# Issues with subfolders not being crawled correctly

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have an issue with a couple folders on one of my sites. There is one folder called Publications_A and one called Publications_B. In each of these folders are a few sub folders (basically archive folders for past years), an index page, and a few documents that are shown on the index page.

Issue 1: The GSA crawls a bunch of documents in the Pub A folder that throw an "not found" error. That's true because those documents are not even there. They are actually located in one of the sub-folders. Even after resetting the index, these still keep showing up here.

Issue 2: The documents that are showing up in the main folder are not showing in the sub folders where they are actually located! I don't get it. In one of the subfolders (named 2014) the GSA is only picking up 5 documents even though there are actually 10 in there. Even if I feed the GSA the full path to these missing documents, it doesn't index them. They are all PDF documents, and there are links to them inside the index.asp file in the 2014 folder. I've checked and there isn't a robots no-crawl tag in any of them.

I've been playing around with this for hours and can't figure it out for the life of me. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use real-time diagnostics to attempt to fetch one of the 'missing' documents and see if you get a "200" response.

Pages that show up that should not could be due to 'relative' links within other content.  For example, a PDF document might have a non-fully qualified URL link inside of it which can cause the GSA to crawl a link that does not really exist.

Make sure your index pages list all of the content you want crawled.

Answer (score 0):

Issue1: If its crawling folders that are not there - then you have your follow path set at a higher level - which will follow any sub folders.

Fix: change follow path / add do not follow path
In addition, as stated by Terry Chambers... If your follow and do not follow paths are correctly listed, then your page content would have a "link" (in some way) to the undesired content (sub folder displayed for A or B).

If folder A has a link that takes u to folder B - then yes it will crawl and index this.
Remove link to avoid undesired effects.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*"Issue 2: The documents that are showing up in the main folder are not showing in the sub folders where they are actually located! I don't get it. In one of the subfolders (named 2014) the GSA is only picking up 5 documents even though there are actually 10 in there. Even if I feed the GSA the full path to these missing documents, it doesn't index them. They are all PDF documents, and there are links to them inside the index.asp file in the 2014 folder. I've checked and there isn't a robots no-crawl tag in any of them."*

PDF documents can have issues crawling/indexing if the content is not "select-able" or in other words the image is "Flat"

You can also try to embed footers/headers (internally or by HTML) in documentation, image type files, etc. This should allow those documents to be crawled and indexed.

Hope this helps.